# Project structures for making API calls in python

Tags: python, structure, project

I am doing my first personal project and I don't know what is the best way to structure my project. It is to create a pennystock screener that screens for stocks that gap up overnight and then filter them based on market cap, premarket volume, price, public float etc.

Right now I've written separate functions that each does its own little thing. I have a function that connects to the REST endpoint to retrieve data, one that uses the data to return a list of stocks that gap up over 50%, and then ones that filter the list of gap ups and return a dictionary of filtered tickers (e.g. ticker name, its float, whether it satisfies the condition of the filter). Then I'd use the value in that dictionary to create another filter (like float rotations based on the values of float that I've stored in the float dictionary). Finally, I have a main function that get the final list of stock which satisfies all the conditions.

The problem is that I don't know how to better structure the project. What I have right now is very inefficient. Take the following snippet as example: for ticker name, i need to call the connect rest function, and then for top gainers, I'm calling ticker names. Then for the float filter, I'm calling the top gainers. For float rotation filter, I need to call the float filter function. Finally with the main function I need to call everything... I’m making api calls in every function. It’s making too many requests and I’d like to store the data after I make the requests.

I don’t know whether to use nested functions, or make global variables, or to write the functions in separate files and then import. Also, I am confused about whether I need to create classes.

```
def connect_REST(data):
    return data


def get_ticker_names(ticker_names, US_listed):
    data = []
    data = connect_REST(data)
    return ticker_names, US_listed

#filter by percent change since last close to get top gainers(>= 50% gap-up pre market)
def get_top_gainer(top_gainer_list):
    return top_gainer_list


# Condition 2: Float > 2M and < 30M
def filter_SharesFloat(floatData, backup_list2):
    top_gainer_list = []
    top_gainer_list = get_top_gainer(top_gainer_list)
    floatData = {}
    backup_list2 = []
    print(floatData)
    print("Float data not available: ", backup_list2)
    return floatData, backup_list2


def filter_float_rotation():
    top_gainer_list = []
    predicted_intra_volume = []
    predicted_intra_volume = get_predicted_intra_volume()
    top_gainer_list = get_top_gainer(top_gainer_list)
    floatData = {}
    floatData = filter_SharesFloat(floatData)

    for ticker in top_gainer_list:
        floatRotations = predictedVolume / floatData[ticker]['float']
        if floatRotations < 1:
            cond_5 = True
        else:
            cond_5 = False
    return floatRotationData

def main():

#get ticker that satisfies condition 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: Yes: Object-oriented programming -- classes -- to model and encapsulate the higher-level concepts. That is usually a better paradigm than global variables or nested functions. Python also lets you segregate things at the module level which is also useful.

Comment: It's hard to get in your head and guess where your project will eventually head to, but I would simply make a class named `RemoteDataCache` that would have methods like `fetch_ticker_names`, `fetch_top_gainer` and whatever else that would actually do REST calls. The methods would store the retrieved data in class's fields like `self.ticker_names = connect_REST(data)`. Once in a while (say every 5 minutes) you would call those methods to update your local data. All the other time you would work only with whatever data is currently stored in `self.ticker_names`.

Comment: Some sorting logic, user interface would be built outside of `RemoteDataCache`, but using its data to operate